# Scale title bars and menu doesn't always work as expected

Tags: unity, gnome, 15.10, scaling

I set scaling factor to 1.38. Menu and title bars indeed always scale properly. What's wrong is that often after I restart computer, window content or top right corner menu content are not scaled properly (i.e. with the factor I set).

What I noticed (and might be of some importance) that the window content and the top right corner menu content are scaled independently from each other - sometimes the window is scaled properly and the menu isn't, sometimes the opposite, sometimes they're both scaled well.

Here's my 'unscaled' chrome window:
[image: unscaled chrome]

And the one scaled properly, which appeared just after restart:
[image: scaled chrome]

Similar thing in Nautilus. This seems to be scaled properly:
[image]

And here, the font is small again:
[image]

Is this behavior a bug? Is there something I can do to deal with it?

Comment: Could you add another screenshot which shows the wrong behavior? In other hand Chrome is a proprietary software, better to submit a bug report to uncle GooGle which could be a quick way.

Comment: @Sneetsher thank you for your answer. I added examples from the same behaviour in Nautilus. So it is not only Chrome, but virtually every window app behaves like this.

Comment: @MarekLipka I know there is a bug about scale not working on the login screen. I have noticed a lot of problem on high ppi screens coming up lately on the forum. What is your screen resolution? I hope unity 8 is better suited to handle different screen resolutions.

Comment: @Torrien my resolution is 1920x1080, but my screen is only 13.3''.  So yes, my screen is high-ppi one.